# Xcode documentation doesn't work offline despite downloads

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been trying to download the SDK documentation for offline reading so that I can reference information with no Internet connection, however Xcode seems to not care that I've downloaded the docs and will only display information if I have an Internet connection. By this I mean I can see the tree on the left pane of the Documentation Viewer but clicking on anything will not load the page unless there is an Internet connection. If I turn my Wi-Fi back on, it immediately works again.

This is occuring on Xcode 5, 6 and 6 beta 4 despite downloading the iOS 8 (for 6+) documentation or any documentation for that matter from the Preferences pane.

Removing the docsets manually, rebooting and then re-downloading them, did not resolve the matter.

Removing the .plist files also did not resolve the matter.
 com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
 com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist

This is happening across all 3 versions of Xcode I have installed so I'm not sure if its deeper than just 1 version.

Is there perhaps another file that says whether it has been downloaded or not that I can clear and re-generate? Or is there perhaps an underlying permissions issue on the docsets?
In Xcode, is there a command line version of loading the app so I can see any error messages?

I have downloaded Dash (http://kapeli.com/dash) and this immediately picked up the docsets I had downloaded and made them available offline. While I can happily use this now, It would be nice to have the integration with Xcode.

Comment: I am getting the same thing in Xcode 6 beta, whether or not I have internet...docs work fine in Xcode 5. Very irritating. If I figure out a fix I will let you know.

Comment: Looks like Xcode 6.1 has the same issue with 10.10 API documentation.

Comment: Dash is awesome. Thanks for the question. Just tried Dash and now I have two separate library one for ios 8 and the other one for the ios 9. No more headache with xcode.

Comment: small correction, looks like you can have only one ios docset at a time. When I install ios9 docset it removes ios 8 docset from my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Xcode 6 Beta 5 has resolved this issue.

Comment: broken for me for the first time in 7.2 too

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem in Xcode 6 GM (!). I only get it with the iOS8 docs, which don't appear to require an internet connection to "download". I managed to get it working at one point by renaming Xcode.app to something else, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. Really annoying.

---

EDIT: It looks like Xcode reads from a folder called `iOSDocsetCD` (containing `iOSDocset.pkg`) deep in `/var/folders/` when it tries to "download" the iOS docs. The folder only appears during the "download" and disappears quickly after, but since there's no network traffic, I can only assume it's getting copied from some cache. If I can clear that cache, perhaps I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An old version of the offline iOS 8 docset (from July 25) is available by looking for the link in [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex)

Here's the direct link (you need to be logged into the dev site):

http://adcdownload.apple.com/reference_library/library_for_ios_8_beta/03105681a.dmg

I'd guess that there will be a new link in the XML page when the full docset is available. The other iOS 8 docset in the page (0315158a.dmg) is even older, from June 2nd.