# Xcode started to not work with downloaded docsets when offline

Tags: xcode, offline, docset

I had a lot of problems trying to download these docsets since updating to the latest Xcode. Various popups appearing saying it didn't know how to install it. Eventually after reading on here I just persisted and their servers started to work so i downloaded a few sets, iOS, WatchOS, and XCode so far. They're downloaded and show as having a tick box next to them.

However even though the docs are downloaded, when I go to use the documentation browser it requires an internet connection to show anything. Sometimes you see it rendering the webpage on apple's site to get the details and then it redraws in the usual documentation form.

I've a few docsets yet to download, but I'm not that bothered about them at this time.

Has anyone else encountered this and got any suggestions?

Comment: Seems its been this way before, a year ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968532/xcode-documentation-doesnt-work-offline-despite-downloads

But I've never encountered or noticed this before

Comment: I've been able to use the Dash app to read the docsets, so that's the workaround I'm using. It does seem like a bug in Xcode that it can't read its own offline docsets.

Comment: I updated OS X and rebooted, at some point the docs were there to download again. Having done so it now seems to work. I was having error messages when it was downloading them the first time so maybe that was why they then didn't work afterwards